# What is the Maven equivelant of a shaded jar in Ant?

Tags: maven, ant

In Maven I can create a self-contained "shaded" jar, and this is exactly what I need. Unfortunately I only have Ant at my disposal.

Is there a way to do this in Ant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [ant-onejar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=getting-started&file=ant) solution.

Comment: As the question states, I only have access to Ant.